# Como hacer peticiones con Postman

Tags: laravel, api, postman

Hola estoy intentando hacer peticiones con Postman pero no entra a la condición no sé que más deba de poner.

de Esta forma es como consulto los datos para visualizarlos en un componente Vue,  Y verifica si la petición es Json.

pero tambien estoy utilizandola como api para acceder desde  ionic. Lo muestra, pero con fines para pruebas. con postman no esta a esa condición y me manda el eror que puse ahí. 404:

Se que en todo funciona, pero aún no tengo todo la app en ionic para hacer las pruebas, por eso necesito primero probarlas en postman. para verificar que  me está dando datos correctos.

```html
public function GetRedes()
 {   
    return request()->wantsJson() ? Network::Buscar()->get() : abort(404);
 }
```

Comment: En Postman tendrás que añadir la cabecera `Accept` con el valor `application/json` para que se cumpla la condición `request()->wantsJson()`

Comment: Hola. Qué versión de Laravel usas?

Answer (score 0):

Conozco dos maneras.

1. Agregar una [excepción](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-excluding-uris) al middleware del kernel web:

   class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
   {
       /**
        * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $except = [
           'api/*',
       ];
   }
2. Usando API routes en vez de web routes.

Es decir, en ves de usar para tu webservice el rutero que está en routes/web.php,
usar routes/api.php.